# Kotlin, embed root_preferences in existing fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

Kotlin, I want to embed root_preferences.xml in a fragment with existing content. I navigate using <navigation..> I want to embed the preferences like this:

```
// ... existing items
<include
        android:id="@+id/summaryPrefs"
        layout="@layout/fragment_container_settings"
/>
// ... more items here
```

What I did

1. Create new Settings Fragment. This does NOT create a layout file, but an XML file at res/xml/root_preferences.xml, make no changes to code.
2. Create a 'container fragment' new Fragment (Blank) name it, ContainerSettingsFragment. it creates the layout file fragment_container_settings.
3. Delete code in class ContainerSettingsFragment and replace with this:
   // Make a container fragment that holds the preference xml.

   ```
    class ContainerSettingsFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container_settings, container, false)
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(
                R.id.settings, // this is the id in fragment_container_settings  <FrameLayout>
                SettingsFragment() // SR: ?? This loads the XML into this fragment
            )
            .commit()
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view
    }
   ```

   }
4. Replaced code in fragment_container_settings with this:
   FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/settings"
   android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:layout_height="300dp"

Expected result: FrameLayout @+id/settings displays the contents of root_preferences
Actual: Size is 250dp x250dp but none of the items are displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was easy, if using nav_graph, don't mix with .supportFragmentManager

1. I removed all the code in the container settings fragment.

   ): View? {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container_settings, container, false)
   }
2. Completed layout in fragment_container_settings.xml

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/settingsSummary"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".ui.settingssummary.ContainerSettingsFragment">

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
3. Used include to add to fragment_settings_summary